# Load large picture from file and add watermark

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I am trying to find an efficient way to load a `Bitmap` from a file containing an arbitrarily large image, place a watermark (a logo) over it, and save it back to file.

I am aware of the memory problems that come with dealing with a large bitmap on Android. I don't want to load a smaller sample of the image, because I need to keep the same quality when saving it back to file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Help with what? What is your question? If the question is "how do I do this", what specifically did you try and what specific problems did you encounter?

Comment: Using BitmapFactory.decodeFile(File) leads to OutOfMemory issues when decoding large pictures. I could load only the portion of bitmap I need to place to watermark in, but then how could I save that portion in the file?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50427/android-help entra che ti passo una logica :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Using BitmapFactory.decodeFile(File) leads to OutOfMemory issues when decoding large pictures

`OutOfMemoryError` occurs because there is no single block of heap space big enough for your request. The Dalvik garbage collector is a non-compacting collector, and so the heap will get fragmented into lots of smaller blocks of memory.

If all of the pictures will be the same resolution, and your `minSdkVersion` is 11 or higher, then allocate the `Bitmap` for it when your process starts up (e.g., in `onCreate()` of a custom `Application` class), and use that with `inBitmap` on your `BitmapFactory.Options`. Your attempt to allocate the `Bitmap` should succeed early on, before your heap gets fragmented, if the image can fit in the heap in the first place.

If they will not all be the same resolution, but you know the maximum resolution, and your `minSdkVersion` is 19 or higher, then do the same thing as I describe above. Android 4.4 extended `inBitmap` to support a `Bitmap` that is the same size or bigger than the image you are loading, whereas before it had to match the size exactly.

If none of that is possible:

- Use `android:largeHeap="true"` to get a larger heap on API Level 11+ devices, or
- Move your image-processing logic to the NDK, as native memory allocations do not count against the Dalvik heap limit, or
- Move your image-processing logic to a dedicated short-lived process, so you get a clean separate heap at the point in time when you need to process a particular image

Those latter three options have costs to the user in terms of the system RAM consumption of your app and other effects.

Comment: Where can I read more about "dedicated short-lived process"? It costs to the user if we do it without telling him, otherwise he's willing to wait. Perhaps.

Comment: @rupinderjeet: I am referring to using `android:process` on some component (e.g., `<service>`) to move it to a separate process, where that component does a chunk of work and then completes (e.g., `stopSelf()).